# How to break bedrock from above in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to break the bedrock blocks on top of the end gateways, but I don't know how.

I only know how to break bedrock from below, so I can break the bedrock blocks underneath the end gateway but not above. It involves pushing an end crystal into a bedrock block and pulling it with a sticky piston. The method can't break bedrock from above because end crystals can only be moved by pushing its pedestal.

Does anyone know how? I couldn't find any Youtube videos on it.

I am playing on 1.16.10

Video showing removal of bedrock with end crystal from beneath:

Comment: Do you have a detailed explanation about how the end crystal method works? It's not a critical question element, but if you have a detailed explanation or a link that can lead us to one, it would certainly be beneficial in providing context that we can work off of.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I linked a video. The reason it works only from below is that you must push an end crystal into the bedrock block you want to remove and you move the bedrock block by moving the block below it.

Comment: I may make an answer later with the details of how this works, but it is worth mentioning that I believe there is an intricate piston method (I think it was done on the SciCraft server) that can delete bedrock from above. You can most likely find a tutorial for that, although I imagine it is costly with resources.

Comment: @Jay I believe SciCraft is a Java edition server, so the method wouldn't work on bedrock. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @PerfectFiasco That is precisely why I didn't make it an answer. I wasn't sure if SciCraft methods supported Bedrock, and at the time, didn't have the time to hunt the internet for Bedrock Edition bedrock destruction methods.

Comment: What you are doing is trying to use a bug that might be working on a different version of the game. I highly recommend to avoid the use of such bugs (as well as for item spawning and duplication) as they might have the possibility to corrupt the entire world save, even if you apparently do it right.